# Is it okay to use two step-up transformers together?

Tags: transformer, ac, dc, inverter

For part of a DIY inverter, I need to use a 12 V to 240 V transformer, preferably over 500 W. I couldn't find any suitable transformers to purchase, however, I found 12 V to 110 V and 110 V to 240 V transformers.

I was wondering if I could use both in a row, first to step the 12 V to 110 V and then step the 110 V up to 240 V or if I should instead make my own DIY 12 V to 240 V transformer from scratch?

Comment: please add links to the datasheets for the two transformers

Comment: Assuming we are talking line frequency here - sure thing. You’ll be loosing some efficiency and have twice the magnitizing current but apart from that should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two transformers in series is usually folly; I'd look for one single transformer that takes 12 volt AC and outputs 240 volts AC. Two in series means you have twice the magnetization losses and twice the magnetization current to cope with and, things could get a little warm on the first transformer.

But, you might experiment (if it's physically possible) with slipping a few turns around the 240 volt transformer and see what the step-down voltage might be. If necessary add or subtract more turns until you get the right 12 volt winding. But be careful here; 240 volts is dangerous and can be lethal so, you need to know what you are doing.

You can test it with 110 volts (if that is your local supply) and, expect to see about 5.5 volts AC from your added winding. Transformers are bidirectional so, if you get 5.5 volts out you can be sure you'll get near enough 240 volts out when you run it in reverse from a 12 volt AC source. But remember that this will be a no-load output voltage; under load the 240 volts may droop so, you may choose to take a turn or two off the newly constructed winding. The old 110 volt secondary winding will no-longer be used.

There is another option; using 2 transformers that step-up from 12 volts to 120 volts; wire the primaries in parallel and, wire the secondaries in series. Again, there are two lots of magnetization current but, as per the two transformers in series, you don't have the first supplying the magnetization current for the second.